# Getting the filename during collection processing in Saxon XSLT

Tags: xml, svg, xslt, saxon

I'm trying to process a directory full of SVG files using XSL-T. I currently have tried:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
                xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xpath-default-namespace="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                exclude-result-prefixes="xsl">
  <xsl:output method="xml" doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template name="main">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
      <defs/>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="collection(concat(resolve-uri('src/images'),'?select=*.svg;content-type=application/xml'))"/>
    </svg>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="svg"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="svg">
    <xsl:element name="symbol">
      <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="tokenize(document-uri(/),'/')[last()]"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:attribute name="viewBox"><xsl:value-of select="@viewBox"/></xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="path"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="path">
    <xsl:element name="path">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@d,@fill"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@d">
    <xsl:attribute name="d"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@fill">
    <xsl:attribute name="fill"><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Using this from the command line: `java net.sf.saxon.Transform -it:main -xsl:"%XSL%\svg-sprite.xsl" -o:"%OUT%\sprite.svg"`

It's sooooo close to working, but I need to get the filename of the included SVG file to use as the `id` attribute on the `<symbol>` element.

I've tried several constructions, using `<xsl:for-each` instead of the `<xsl:apply-templates` and everything else I could think of, but I just can't get it to access the filename.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your attempt with `document-uri` fails, that is by now a known issue in Saxon as various requirements of the specs made Saxonica change its implementation; there is an [issue](https://github.com/qt4cg/qtspecs/issues/898) in the ongoing XPath 4 work to relax the requirements so that `document-uri`'s functionality can be restored.

But in most uses cases `base-uri` will do so try that.

As an alternative you can start with `uri-collection` instead of `collection`, then you directly have the URI of each collection of which you can easily extract the file name, and process the document using `doc($uri)` with e.g. `apply-templates`.

Comment: Well @Martin Honnen, you're 2 for 2!  `base-uri` did the trick.  With a little `tokenize` love around the edges (e.g. `tokenize(base-uri(),'/|\.')[last() - 1]`) it worked like a charm.  This little SVG Sprite Sheet generator is nearly finished.  I think I owe you a beer!